# Modifying FormAuthentication 302 redirect behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to intercept the FormAuthentication 302 redirect code where it checks where a user is allowed to view a page or not and if he is not the module sends the user to '/login.aspx?ReturnURL="Requestedpage.aspx". I want to add custom query string here.

Edit: URL rewriting will not work for me. I want to intercept that code only. I want to set custom headers too from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [URL Rewriting](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/) to set up a rule so that the URL `/login.aspx?ReturnURL="Requestedpage.aspx` is rewritten to whatever you require.